# Convert .XYZ to .csv using c#

Tags: c#, csv

Hi i am using this method to replace " " to "," but is failing when i try to use it on data that have 32 millions lines. Is anyone knows how to modify it to make it running?

```
            List<String> lines = new List<String>();

            //loop through each line of file and replace " " sight to ","
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputfile))
            {
                int id = 1;

                int i = File.ReadAllLines(inputfile).Count();
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    //Out of memory issuee
                    string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();

                    //do something with line
                    string ttt = fileLine.Replace(" ", ", ");

                    //Debug.WriteLine(ttt);
                    lines.Add(ttt);
                    //lines.Add(id++, 'ID');
                }

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputfile, false))
                {
                    foreach (String line in lines)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(line+","+id);
                        id++;                     
                    }                       
                }                
            }

            //change extension to .csv
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(outputfile);
            f.MoveTo(Path.ChangeExtension(outputfile, ".csv"));
```

I general i am trying to convert big .XYZ file to .csv format and add incremental field at the end. I am using c# for first time in my life to be honest :) Can you help me?

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: Don't `ReadAllLines` while you have a `StreamReader` open on the same file. Since it appears you don't you don't even use `i`, it should be safe to delete the line. Also, just set your `outputfile` to have the ".csv" extension in the first place, then you don't need the `MoveTo`...

Comment: I knew i am doing something wrong...  Program throwing Out of memory error at this line --       string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();

Comment: That gives a big clue. Why are you reading all of the data into memory first and then writing it out. Why not read a line, do your replacements, append the id & then write the line immediately. No real need to keep 32 million lines in memory.

Comment: The reason of that is when I solving the task I first try to make program doing what I want and after that i am improving my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above - you could modify your reading / writing as follows :

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputfile))
  {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputfile, false))
    {
      int id = 1;

      while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
      {
        string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();

        //do something with line
        string ttt = fileLine.Replace(" ", ", ");
        writer.WriteLine(ttt + "," + id);
        id++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for sorting my code, but it still rising an error 'out of memory' when I try to use ReadLine(); on big files

Comment: Are you still creating a list in memory?